# How to have comments in intellisense from services references methods?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, comments, intellisense

I have a C# WCF Service with methods which have comments in summary. I'm using Services References from my WPF Project (Client).

I commented in my interface:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Allow to get Template
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    Template GetTemplate();
```

And in my service too:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Allow to get Template
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Template GetTemplate()
    {
        return new Template();
    }
```

I can use my methods from my client:

```
Template template = myServiceReferenceClient.GetTemplate();
```

But, I want my comments ("Allow to get Template" in this case) in the Intellisense from my client that way:

[image: that way]

I checked "XML document file" in my service project properties to have comments but it doesn't work. I think the issue is because I'm using Service References:

[image: Services References]

Comment: You are correct that the service reference is the problem because the code which your client is consuming is a bastardised, across the wire representation of the actual service types and definition.